# Can't install some gem

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, rubygems

I try install some gem ([roo](http://roo.rubyforge.org)) under Linux.

`# uname -a Ubuntu-1304-raring-64-minimal 3.8.0-19-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 1 16:35:23 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

But responded error:

```
# gem install roo
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing roo:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby extconf.rb

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

Why?

Comment: Do you have `gcc` installed?

Comment: @KepaniHaole, yes, gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) installed.

Answer (score 0):

You use system Ruby that need `ruby-dev` package to install native extensions. I suggest to switch to any version manager like RVM or rbenv. After that this error should disappear.